# How can I list directories that are used by unionfs?

Tags: linux, mount

On a debian server, I have unionfs mounted with no entry in fstab. How can I figure out the command, that was used to mount it (or which directories make up the union) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `/proc/mounts`. In many cases `/etc/mtab` will also contain this information.

Edit: The above will work for unionfs, the 'original one', implemented as kernel module. As you are using the user-space alternative – unionfs-fuse, things are a bit different.

In this case try looking for unionfs-fuse command line:

```
ps -wfC unionfs-fuse
```

Example:

```
[root@lolek ~]# unionfs-fuse -o cow -o allow_other -o use_ino -o nonempty /tmp/a=RW:/tmp/b=RO /tmp/c 
[root@lolek ~]# ps -wfC unionfs-fuse                                                                 
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      3943     1  0 19:08 ?        00:00:00 unionfs-fuse -o cow -o allow_other -o use_ino -o nonempty /tmp/a=RW:/tmp/b=RO /tmp/c
```

Comment: Only the mount point and options are displayed in both cases.

Comment: The options should include the directories mounted. It works for me: `none /etc unionfs rw,relatime,dirs=/rw/etc=rw:/rootfs_ro/etc=ro 0 0` ('Unionfs 2.5.3 (for 2.6.31)')

What UnionFS version do you use?

Comment: unionfs-fuse version: 0.21

Comment: Then it is quite a different thing.